# Multivariable calculus: optimizing for shortest path along a curvy plane?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, integration, graph-theory, optimization

I want to write a computer program which can help me spend the least amount of energy and time walking between locations on my university campus. My campus is very hilly, and it is also extremely hot during the early fall, so I would like to optimize for the least energy used.

I want my program to answer a few questions:

- When is walking uphill for a short distance more favorable than walking a longer roundabout path that is flatter or downhill?
- Walking distances causes internal temperature to rise, but so does standing in the sun for too long. Which path on a certain day with given weather inputs (sunny, hot) would cause the least amount of sweating?

(note: Only educated up to single-variable calculus.) This animated image seems to be visually what I am going for:

[image: integration over a curved surface]

I have a feeling this is a simple calculus question where I need to choose different paths. For each path, I need to find the integral of the angle of elevation and then compare it to the last path I calculated, then the lowest number is my answer.

How do I formulate this integral?

Comment: Finding geodesics on a curved surface is a very difficult to implement using computer programming. It is not a simple calculus problem, actually far from simple, you can set up a calculus of variation problem on discrete grids which can capture the curvature of this surface.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is nice to have confirmation that it is a hard problem and not just something I haven't learned of yet. For now, I have decided to do something similar to what you suggested, by using a discrete grid. I will be implementing Dijkstra's algorithm using Google's Elevation API as my data source.

Comment: Yes, definitely! Mathematically for continuous smooth surface, this is a definitely a hard problem. In discrete level, like you said (a hint to myself), you can either try adapting Dijkstra's algorithm to grids with $z$-data, or directly working on a 3D grids mesh.